# Is there a URL that will start playing "My Mix"?

Tags: youtube

I love the "My Mix" feature on Youtube.  It chooses better songs than any other streaming service I've tried.

However, Youtube has a major problem: it's distracting. The homepage that shows "My Mix" also shows many other videos.

Therefore, I'd like a direct link to "My mix".  I'd put it on my bookmarks, and with a simple click, I can get straight to music.

(The link on the homepage doesn't work AFAIK, because it links to a specific instance of "My Mix", meaning the same list of songs everytime)

(It doesn't have to be a URL either.  A bookmarklet or something similar: I simply want a button on my browser to start music)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alex's answer works if combined with a zero-second video!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mvvsa5HAJiI&list=RDMM&start_radio=1

Comment: I didn't expect this to work, but it totally does.

Comment: I found this question because I was looking for the very same thing. Even after reading Leo's & Mostze+Alex's answers it took me some experimentation to get it working. I suspect that the more people who use it, the more likely YouTube is to implement a standard feature; so please do Share!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a satisfying answer for this, unfortunately.

- The thing does have an ID, namely `RDMM`. But unlike other things that have this, looking at it in the playlist viewer breaks the site: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDMM (It does work for other playlist-y things such as [Watch Later](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=WL)). I can try to get YouTube to fix this, but this likely won't get a too high priority.
- If you [search for My Mix](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=my+mix), the first result should be your "My Mix". If you can get some muscle memory going, you might get quite quickly to your destination.

  - It might be possible to make a bookmarklet to automate that, but I suppose programming that would be more of a stackoverflow question. I wouldn't know how to anyways.
- There exists a [YouTube Music app](https://music.youtube.com) for phones which would have a "My station" thing prominently featured. If you live in Australia, South Korea, Mexico, New Zealand and the US, that is.

Comment: Unfortunately the YouTube Music app has the same restrictions for non-Red users:  You have to keep your screen on.

Answer (score 2):

Put `&list=RDMM&start_radio=1` at the end of the video link.

Comment: Mostze, could you elaborate on your answer? Why does adding those parameters to the URL work? Is it documented somewhere? Could you provide an example?